# .Net implicit conversion guidelines

Tags: c#, types, implicit

What are general guidelines on when user-defined implicit conversion could, should, or should not be defined?

I mean things like, for example, "an implicit conversion should never lose information", "an implicit conversion should never throw exceptions", or "an implicit conversion should never instantiate new objects". I am pretty sure the first one is correct, the third one is not (or we could only ever have implicit conversion to structs), and I don't know about the second one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first isn't as simple as you might expect. Here's an example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long firstLong = long.MaxValue - 2;
        long secondLong = firstLong - 1;

        double firstDouble = firstLong;
        double secondDouble = secondLong;

        // Prints False as expected
        Console.WriteLine(firstLong == secondLong);

        // Prints True!
        Console.WriteLine(firstDouble == secondDouble);        
    }
}
```

Personally I very rarely create my own implicit conversions. I'm happy enough with the ones in the framework, but I rarely feel that adding my own would make life better. (The same is true of value types in general, btw.)

EDIT: Just to actually answer the question a bit, it's probably worth reading the [conversion operators part of the Microsoft class library design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229059.aspx).

Comment: Ouch! Well, this rather suggests to me that this implicit conversion is a bit broken.

Comment: You do delve into weirdness, don't you?? Where did you come up with this one? :)

Comment: @Andrew: well they both have 64 bits and not every double is an integer. Stands to reason there'll be some integers which can't be represented exactly.

Comment: I would not regard as surprising the fact that `firstDouble==secondDouble`. What I would consider "surprising" is that `firstLong == secondDouble` compiles without diagnostic and returns true. The assignments to `firstDouble` and `secondDouble` cannot be expected to do anything but make `firstDouble` hold the best available `double` representations of `firstLong` and `secondLong`.  By comparison, since `==` has an overload whose first operator type would require conversion, and one where it would not, I would favor a compiler diagnostic there.

Comment: @supercat: In both cases the conversion is implicit but can lose information. I'd want either both conversions to cause a warning/error, or neither.

Comment: Conceptually, there's no reason `==` should have to convert its arguments to the same type; some mixed-type overloads could offer meanings not obtainable via any other means [e.g. (long,ulong) and (ulong,long)]. I would posit that when the destination type is obvious, a "fuzzy" conversion without a typecast is clearer than one with, since most explicit typecasts will guarantee that if they succeed, the source values was precisely representable in the destination type. Saying `double X = someLong;` would make clear that X will be a value that's fits in double, whether or not `someLong` does.

Comment: 99% of everything computers do "loses information".  Shedding information *which will never be needed* is a good thing. Do you think `g.DrawLine(myPen, (float)myX1, (float)myY1, (float)myX2, (float)myY2)` is clearer than `g.DrawLine(myPen, myX1, myY1, myX2, myY2)`?  The extra precision of `double` may be relevant to the surrounding code, but it isn't relevant to `DrawLine`.  IMHO, `foo=something`; should compile without diagnostic if it will likely make `foo` hold the best representation, or an essentially-equally-good one, of anything for which `something` holds the best representation.

Comment: @supercat: Again, I think we're not going to agree and SO comment threads aren't an appropriate medium for the discussion. If we ever meet up in person, there'll be a lot to talk about...

Comment: I would posit that for any pair of values of types T and U, if `var myT = (T)someU; return (myT == otherU)` should not return anything other than `(someU == otherU)`. If it can't promise that, it should throw an exception at the explicit typecast or fail to compile altogether. If `T` is `float` and `U` is `double`, however, that won't work.  Converting to `float`, whether implicitly or explicitly, says "Shed the lower bits since I don't need them". Using a `float` as `double`, however, suggests that the bits probably are needed after all--they just don't exist (oops).

Comment: @supercat: Please see my previous comment. I'm really *not* going to get drawn into this.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess my original point was that *with regard to your example* [reason for commenting here], even people who understand how `double` works and aren't surprised by `firstDouble == secondDouble` might still find `firstDouble == secondLong` to be surprising (since it's not obvious that it should be equivalent to `firstDouble == (double)secondLong` and not `(ExtendedDouble)firstDouble == (ExtendedDouble)secondLong`).

Answer (score 2):

I'd agree with the first definitely - the second most of the time ("never say never"), but wouldn't get excited by the third; apart from anything else, it creates an unnecessary distinction between structs and classes. In some cases, having an implicit conversion can vastly simplify a calling convention.

For explicit conversions, all things are possible.

It isn't that often you need to write conversion operators, though. And in many cases, explicit operators are more useful, with the acceptance that they can break if conditions aren't right (for example, with `Nullable<T>`, if they don't have a value).

Answer (score 1):

If you will only be supporting implicit conversions among objects of your own types, I would suggest that you should decide on what "axioms" should apply to such conversions (e.g. it may be helpful to decide that if `a==b`, `b==c`, and `a==c` are all legal and two of them are true, the third must also be true) and then identify a the most useful set of conversions which would make those axioms hold.  I discuss four useful axioms on my blog at http://supercatnet.blogspot.com/2013/09/axioms-of-implicit-type-conversion.html (unfortunately, the .NET Framework includes conversions which violate all four, while disallows conversions which wouldn't have to).

An important thing to consider is that implicit conversions *to* imprecise types will in most contexts pose a smaller risk of astonishment than than conversions *from* imprecise types, but there's a notable exception: if something of a more-precise type is fed to a method or operator which has overloads that take both the more-precise type and a less-precise type to which it can be converted, some level of "astonishing" behavior will be almost inevitable unless one can make implicit conversion impossible [e.g. the behavior if programmer writes `if (someLong == someFloat)` may be astonishing, but not because the loss of precision on an implicit `long` to `float` conversion is astonishing, but rather because there are at least six different ways one might want to compare a `long` and a `float`(*), and *any* meaning the compiler might attach to a direct comparison would astonish those who expected something else.  The only solution I know of to avoid such astonishment is to provide overloads to explicitly cover all ambiguous cases and mark them with an `[Obsolete()]` tag.  Doing that is apt to be somewhat awkward, but would offer the substantial advantage of being able to satisfy all four axioms.

(*) A programmer might plausibly be intending to test whether the long was equal to the value of the float rounded to nearest, truncated toward zero, or floored toward negative infinity; alternatively, the programmer might be wanting to test whether the `float` was the one that represents the `long`, whether the `float` and `long` have the same nominal value, or whether the `float` and `long` would both convert to the same `double`.

Answer (score 0):

The borderline case which caused me to ask this question is a violation of the second one. Namely, I have a Lazy<T> class (doesn't everyone?) and started pondering whether I shouldn't provide an implicit conversion to T. My instinct is to say yes, and the current version does, but I am not too sure.

Comment: No, I really wouldn't - as you're potentially doing significant work, it feels wrong to make it implicit. Have an *explicit* conversion, perhaps - but if you're looking for "why is this suddenly executing some code?" an implicit conversion is too easy to miss.

Comment: After thinking over it a bit more, I am inclined to agree after all.

Comment: Or even a method, such as GetValue()

Comment: Await() in my case, inherited from Future<T>